# How to compare column values of pandas groupby object and summarize them in a new column row

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following problem: I want to create a column in a dataframe summarizing all values in a row. Then I want to compare the rows of that column to create a single row containg all the values from all columns, but so that each value is only present a single time. As example: I have the following data frame

```
    df1:

  Column1 Column2
0    a     1,2,3
1    a     1,4,5
2    b     7,1,5
3    c     8,9
4    b     7,3,5
```

the desired output would now be:

```
df1_new:

  Column1 Column2
0    a    1,2,3,4,5
1    b    1,3,5,7
2    c    8,9
```

What I am currently trying is `result = df1.groupby('Column1')`, but then I don't know how to compare the values in the rows of the grouped objects and then write them to the new column and removing the duplicates. I read through the pandas documentation of Group By: split-apply-combine but could not figure out a way to do it. I also wonder if, once I have my desired output, there is a way to check in how many of the lines in the grouped object each value in Column2 of df1_new appeared. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the type of `Column2` right now? What do you get when you do - `print(type(df1['Column2'][0]))` ?

Comment: Please, provide the code to construct the DataFrame

Comment: @AnandSKumar The type of Column2 is a series right now `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`.                                                                                                                                                                                         @ssoler Column2 was created like this: `ResData['AR_Genes'] = ResData[ResData.columns[1:10]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str).astype(str)),axis=1)` and then merged with the already existing Column1 using a left merge.

Comment: So that means the type of elements of column2 is `str` , not Series. You should have outputted the result of the `print` statement I gave, would have been much clearer to everyone. Do you care about the order in the resulting `Column2` , order of elements inside the strings in `Column2` .?

Comment: @AnandSKumar the code I outputted in the sentence directed to you is the result of your `print` statement. No, the order of elements is not important. I think I should do some more tutorials on pandas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method by which you can do this would be to apply a function on the grouped DataFrame.

This function would first convert the series (for each group) to a list, and then in the list split each string using `,` and then chain the complete list into a single list using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and then convert that to `set` so that only unique values are left and then sort it and then convert back to string using `str.join` . Example -

```
from itertools import chain
def applyfunc(x):
    ch = chain.from_iterable(y.split(',') for y in x.tolist())
    return ','.join(sorted(set(ch)))

df1_new = df1.groupby('Column1')['Column2'].apply(func1).reset_index()
```

Demo -

```
In [46]: df
Out[46]:
  Column1 Column2
0       a   1,2,3
1       a   1,4,5
2       b   7,1,5
3       c     8,9
4       b   7,3,5

In [47]: from itertools import chain

In [48]: def applyfunc(x):
   ....:         ch = chain.from_iterable(y.split(',') for y in x.tolist())
   ....:         return ','.join(sorted(set(ch)))
   ....:

In [49]: df.groupby('Column1')['Column2'].apply(func1).reset_index()
Out[49]:
  Column1    Column2
0       a  1,2,3,4,5
1       b    1,3,5,7
2       c        8,9
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, when I try to run it I get the Error `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'` which gets traced back to  `df.groupby('Column1'['Coulmn2'].apply(applyfunc).reset_index()`. Could it have to do with the fact that there are `NaN` in some of the rows in Column2?

Comment: yea it could, maybe you can put a condition to check for `NaN` before doing `y.split` in the function.

Comment: Strangely the condition that removed all the `nan` did not work. But I could resolve it through putting the output of the condition in a new df and apply the code on that, that worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
df1
      Column1 Column2
    0       a   1,2,3
    1       a   1,4,5
    2       b   7,1,5
    3       c     8,9
    4       b   7,3,5

df1.groupby('Column1').\
agg(lambda x: ','.join(x).split(','))['Column2'].\
apply(lambda x: ','.join(np.unique(x))).reset_index()

  Column1    Column2
0       a  1,2,3,4,5
1       b    1,3,5,7
2       c        8,9
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, when I try to run your code it get `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (42, 2), indices imply (42, 1)`. Since my data (strings) are in the same format as in the example, my only explanation is the presence of `NaN` values in some of the rows of column2...

Comment: @sequence_hard Is it `NaN` as one of the figures in the string, or total row as `NaN`, or any

Comment: `NaN` is sometimes a value in Column2, but never in Column1